# RikuloGap Geolocation

Tags: cordova, dart, rikulo

I'm learning to use RikuloGap to write a PhoneGap Application using Dart Languages instead of Javascript.

In the API Reference on Rikulo site, I read:

> Based on Cordova/PhoneGap, Rikulo Gap currently supports nine native
>   device features across seven mobile platforms including Android, iOS,
>   and others. Rikulo Gap bridge Dart to Cordova's JavaScript APIs and
>   get accessed to the following nine native device services:
>
> Accelerometer: access to the device's motion sensor.
>   Camera: capture a photo with the device camera.
>   Capture: capture media files using device's media capture application.
>   Compass: access to the device's compass sensor.
>   Connection: fetch the device's connection information.
>   Contacts: read/update/create/remove the device's contact list.
>   Device: fetch the device's basic information.
>   Geolocation: access to the device's geographic location sensor.
>   Notification: trigger the device's visual/audible/vibration notifications.

However, reading RikuloGap DartDoc uploaded on Pub or analyzing the source code on GitHub I can find only references to:

> rikulo_accelerometer
>   rikulo_contact
>   rikulo_device
>   rikulo_notification

So, was the support for geolocation, camera etc. never implemented od dropped in the recent releases? if it's still there, can you tell me the right imports and how to use the APIs?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tom Yeh from Rikulo replied to me via email:

> Hi Gianluca,
>
> Due to a lot of changes to Cordova and Dart SDK, we rewrote in 0.6.
>   Please make sure you get the right api:
>     http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/rikulo_gap/0.6.0+1/index.html#rikulo_gap
>
> However, we don’t have time to make all services available. You can
>   help:)
>
> Regards

so they dropped the support to various cordova APIs in the recent releases ... and they are not planning to re-implement these APIs.